# extend border line to the bottom of page tabs-left bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

The line to the right of inbox, sent , archived, trash; I want it to go all the way down to the bottom of the screen and I have no idea how to do that.  I'm using bootstrap 3.0 and this css code to make the tabs come from the left

```
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
    display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
    display: block;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li {
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
    border-top-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
    border-color: transparent #ddd #ddd #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li {
    float: none;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
    min-width: 74px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 19px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
    margin-right: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
    border-color: #eeeeee #dddddd #eeeeee #eeeeee;
}

.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
    border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd #ddd;
    *border-right-color: #ffffff;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 19px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
    border-color: #eeeeee #eeeeee #eeeeee #dddddd;
}

.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
    border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
    *border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?